# What is the main advantage of defining a separate interface for a class of its own, which the class then implements?

Tags: java, class, interface

What is the main advantage of defining a separate interface for a class of its own, which the class then implements in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, nothing. It's a somewhat commonly observed but quite outdated pattern. You know you're doing it wrong if you can't think of a good way to name the interface and the implementing class differently - i.e. if you end up writing `public interface IWhatsAppClient` and `public class WhatsAppClient implements IWhatsAppClient`, that's the clear sign you messed up. A much better take would be `public interface MessageClient` and `public class WhatsappClient extends MessageClient` - now it makes sense: Perhaps later on you add more client impls, for telegram and signal or whatnot.

A few advantages:

- Even if a whatsapp client is all you ever intend to write and your interface in fact includes whatsapp specific stuff because you need it in your main code, by using an interface+class model you can make a second implementation that just gives dummy answers. Useful to write tests (you really, *really* do not want your unit tests to require an actual whatsapp business account or whatnot!)
- Software often tends to be structured similarly to the organization that makes the software ([Conway's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law). Opinions differ on whether this is a bad thing (as in, fight it: Be highly skeptical if you end up with as many packages as dev teams, etc), or whether it is a good thing and that thus you e.g. design first and then set up as many dev teams as design dictates, or that software design matching organizational structure is inherently an advantageous thing.  If you are of the opinion that it can be advantageous, Conway's Law can show up in interface+class design. For example, if there is one team that writes software that needs the ability to interact with customers over a messaging service. There is a completely different team responsible for actually making that work. In such a case it can be advantageous to let the customer-side team write that interface (after all, they know exactly what they need it to do now and in the near future), and then maintain this interface, even though the third party services integration team is not now or ever planning on adding support for more messaging services.

Personally I think Conway's is mostly downside; there is a correct answer in software design and a correct answer in organizational structures and they often but do not always match up. If they don't match up, conway's is to be fought, not embraced. But that's just opinion - yours may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Well...a class can have many methods of different access specifiers. One way is you carefully handle each and every methods in it. Other way is, you expose only the interface and there you keep only those methods which you want to expose. so, even if something is loosely present in the class, since it can't be accessed directly, it will be safe.